# Get absolute address of range

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

In old school Excel Interop, I can use the following code to generate an absolute address and use it inside a formula:

```cs
range.Formula = $"=sum({myRange.Address[false, true]})";
```

What is the EPPlus equivalent of this line, to get an absolute address (with an absolute row and/or column on demand)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there isn't a built in method, but you can do the following:

```
string GetAddress(ExcelRange rgn, bool absoluteRow, bool absoluteColumn,bool includeSheetName=false)
{
    string address = rgn.Address;
    if (absoluteColumn)
    {
        address = Regex.Replace(address, @"\b([A-Z])", @"$$$1");
    }
    if (absoluteRow)
    {
        address = Regex.Replace(address, @"([0-9]+)", @"$$$1");
    }
    if (includeSheetName)
    {
        address = $"'{rgn.Worksheet.Name}'!{address}";
    }
    return address;
}
```

Or as an extension method, so you can use like interop:

```
public static class EpplusExtensions
{
    public static string Address(this ExcelRange rgn, bool absoluteRow, bool absoluteColumn, bool includeSheetName=false)
    {
        string address = rgn.Address;
        if (absoluteColumn)
        {
            address = Regex.Replace(address, @"\b([A-Z])", @"$$$1");
        }
        if (absoluteRow)
        {
            address = Regex.Replace(address, @"([0-9]+)", @"$$$1");
        }
        if (includeSheetName)
        {
            address = $"'{rgn.Worksheet.Name}'!{address}";
        }
        return address;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (var ep = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(file)))
{
    var sh = ep.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
    ExcelRange myRange = sh.Cells[1, 1, 26, 36];
    var absoluteColumn = myRange.Address(false, true);
    var absoluteRow = myRange.Address(true, false);
    var absolute = myRange.Address(true, true);
    var relative = myRange.Address(false, false);
    var withSheetName = myRange.Address(true, true, true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For an approach, that uses only EPPlus methods, there are static methods like `ExcelCellBase.GetAddress` (with a couple of overloads) that return absolute addresses:

```cs
public abstract class ExcelCellBase
{
    public static string GetAddress(
        int Row,
        int Column,
        bool Absolute
    );

    public static string GetAddress(
        int Row,
        bool AbsoluteRow,
        int Column,
        bool AbsoluteCol
    );

    public static string GetAddress(
          int FromRow,
          int FromColumn,
          int ToRow,
          int ToColumn,
          bool FixedFromRow,
          bool FixedFromColumn,
          bool FixedToRow,
          bool FixedToColumn
    );

    /* ... and others, see comments */
}
```

An extension method could be as easy as this one:

```cs
public static class EpPlusExtensions
{
    public static string GetAddress(
        this ExcelRangeBase range,
        bool absoluteRow = false,
        bool absoluteColumn = false)
    {
        return ExcelCellBase.GetAddress(
            range.Start.Row,
            range.Start.Column,
            range.End.Row,
            range.End.Column,
            absoluteRow,
            absoluteColumn,
            absoluteRow,
            absoluteColumn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my update, Added a option to use sheet name and it works for only column or only rows addresses. Also, `ExcelCellBase.GetAddress` doesn't have a option for support sheet names or only column or only row addresses.

Comment: Looks good now! It's a nice little method that should more or less even universally work with other libraries, so I will accept it as the answer.
As for `ExcelCellBase`, there are more overloads and additional methods like `GetAddressRow(int Row, bool Absolute = false)` and `GetAddressCol(int Col, bool Absolute = false)`, for absolute entire rows or columns. To get the sheet name included, use `GetFullAddress(string worksheetName, string address)`.